# Does Angular Have an Equivalent to C#'s "UsePathBase"

Tags: angular, routes, load-balancing, aws-application-load-balancer

We have an angular application behind an AWS ALB. The load balancer directs traffic to the angular app when requests are made to a certain route `example.com/balancer-route/...`. But this then means that requests hit the angular app with the additional `balancer-route` in the URI. We need these to be ignored so files are served correctly.

Is there an equivalent to `app.UseBasePath` in C#? In C# this would essential ignore the `/balancer-route` part of the requests and serve the endpoints as normal. It would also continue to serve requests when the base path is not present.

We're aware this can be solved using NGINX but would prefer an application based solution where the path could be passed to the application at runtime.

Comment: The baseHref, see [docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-base-tag)

Comment: Thanks for the response @Drenai and @Eliseo. I was aware of `bareHref`, but I don't think that's an appropriate solution. Reading the docs that is for hosting on a multi tenanted server where you're application lives in a subfolder. Additionally it's set in the html so not at runtime, although I do see there is `APP_BASE_HREF` where you can DI this

Answer (score 0):

By using the **redirect** capabilities of Angular Routing you can get what you are looking for.
Take this routes for example:

```js
    const routes: Routes = [
       { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
       { path: 'quotes', component: QuoteListComponent },
       { path: 'quote/:id', component: QuoteComponent }
    ];
```

you can surf to `http://some.com/`, `http://some.com/quotes` and `http://some.com/quote/1`,

and, you want to redirect to traffic from `http://some.com/balancer-route`, `http://some.com/balancer-route/quotes` and `http://some.com/balancer-route/quote/1` to the first routes examples respectively.

Therefore we will group all our Routes into one object with children routes, and we will add another Route with reidrect to the same object that groups all the routes

```js
    const routes: Routes = [
       {
          path: '', children: [
             { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
             { path: 'quotes', component: QuoteListComponent },
             { path: 'quote/:id', component: QuoteComponent }
          ]
       }, {
          path: 'balancer-route', redirectTo: ''
       }
    ];
```